# Need help converting Tradingview pine script from v2 to v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am new to TradingView Pine script. I am seeking for help with a pine script which is on version 2 right now but I am trying convert it into Version 5 and is having so many compilation errors.

Can anyone pls help me

Error i m getting

line 15: Undeclared identifier `buying`;
line 19: Undeclared identifier `buying`;
line 24: Undeclared identifier `buying`;
line 25: Undeclared identifier `longCondition`;
line 28: Undeclared identifier `buying`;
line 29: Undeclared identifier `shortCondition`

Here is the script i am trying to convert

```
//@version=2

strategy("TG Booster", shorttitle="TG Booster", overlay=false)

threshold = input(title="Price Difference Threshold", type=float, defval=0.004, step=0.001)


getDiff() =>
    yesterday=security(tickerid, 'D', close[1])
    today=security(tickerid, 'D', close)
    delta=today-yesterday
    percentage=delta/yesterday
    
closeDiff = getDiff()
buying = closeDiff > threshold ? true : closeDiff < -threshold ? false : buying[1]

hline(0, title="zero line")

bgcolor(buying ? yellow : purple, transp=25)
plot(closeDiff, color=silver, style=area, transp=75)
plot(closeDiff, color=black, title="prediction")


longCondition = buying
if longCondition
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)

shortCondition = buying != true
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)
```

Need help converting Tradingview pine script from version 2 to version 5

Answer (score 0):

you can't declare the variable 'buying' and ask for the value of buying before the creation (the buying[1] part).
The converted script is :

```
//@version=5

strategy("TG Booster", shorttitle="TG Booster", overlay=false)

threshold = input.float(0.004, title="Price Difference Threshold", step=0.001)


getDiff() =>
    yesterday=request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close[1])
    today=request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close)
    delta=today-yesterday
    percentage=delta/yesterday
    
closeDiff = getDiff()
var bool buying = na
buying := closeDiff > threshold ? true : closeDiff < -threshold ? false : buying[1]

hline(0, title="zero line")

bgcolor(buying ? color.yellow : color.purple, transp=25)
plot(closeDiff, color=color.silver, style=plot.style_area , transp=75)
plot(closeDiff, color=color.black, title="prediction")


longCondition = buying
if longCondition
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)

shortCondition = buying != true
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)
```

Comment: G.Lebret, thanks for your help, but the output of the code totally differs then what I shared in v2 and shows too many wrong signals, and accuracy gets decreased. Can you help me with a solution?

Comment: @SachinNayi I didn’t modify the logic of your script, only the ´grammar’ so that it is compliant with the v5 way of programming. If the converted script works, please accept the answer. If you want to ´optimize ´ your script, please open a new question as asking in comment is forbiden.